# Possible to prevent "docker pull" from loading into RAM?

Tags: memory, docker

I'm trying to perform a `docker pull` of an image that has one component that's 6 GB in size.  Unfortunately, Docker seems to want to bring the entire thing into active memory before writing it to disk, and the machine only has 4 GB of RAM, so it's hammering the entire system to a halt.

Is it possible to get `docker pull` to just put its artifacts on disk and not store them in RAM?

Comment: Does the image contain history? It could be shrunk using export+import.

Comment: @harrymc: Probably some, but I don't think the history is likely to be much of the bulk of the data.

Comment: I know of a case where this halved the size of the image.